# HashSet compilation error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, hashset

The only thing I want to do is putting an array (temp_X) into a HashSet, but I got the error for the HashSet: no suitable constructor found for HashSet(List)

```
 public PSResidualReduction(int Xdisc[][], double[][] pat_cand, int k) {

        for (int i = 0; i < Xdisc.length; i++) {
            int[] temp_X;
            temp_X = new int[Xdisc[0].length];
            for (int s = 0; s < Xdisc[0].length; s++) {
                temp_X[s] = Xdisc[i][s];
            }
            HashSet<Integer> temp_XList = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(temp_X));
        }

    }
```

Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arrays#asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) accepts a type array which means all elements used need to be `Object` types rather than primitives.

Use an `Integer` array instead:

```
Integer[] temp_X;
```

This will allow `Arrays#asList` to be used to against the wrapper class:

```
HashSet<Integer> temp_XList = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(temp_X));
```

Comment: @Vahid Reimeus is not suggesting that you don't use a `HashSet`. He's suggesting that you change `temp_X` from an `int[]` to an `Integer[]`. Alternately change `temp_X` to a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I did not read the solution completely before.

Answer (score 1):

in  `Arrays.asList(temp_X);` `temp_X` must be a Object array,not primitive type array. And `HashSet<T>` does not support primitive type .You have to convert each int in temp_X to `Integer` and add to temp_xList one by one